# render woo rest apI to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to get woo rest api on my rect site, i need to be able to get, put, and delete.

after reading the docs, where no where seems to mention the headers issues un less o use node, my question is, there is a way to get the render in react without using nodejs cors, or it's a must to use node to render woo rest api.

[image]

```
 woo.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";


const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
url: "https://example.com/",
consumerKey: "ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
consumerSecret: "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 version: "wc/v3"
 });

const WooSolo =()=>{
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 fetchOrders();
}, []);

 let fetchOrders = () => {
 api
.get("orders", {
  per_page: 20,
})
.then((response) => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    setOrders(response.data);
   console.log(response.data);
   }
  })
   .catch((error) => {});
  };

   console.log(orders);
   return (
  <div>

 <h1>woo single site here</h1>

   </div>

  )
 }

export default WooSolo;
```

is this has to be done with node to get the data then pass onto react please explain me how. or if there is another method in react instead of this.

I thought it was cause I was using localhost, but I deployed on Heroku and still not able to render anything with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is CORS on your WordPress installation.
Can you try to add this in your function.php file?
Replace `yourfrontenddomain` to the domain you are using as frontend.

```
add_action('init', 'handle_preflight');
function handle_preflight() {
    $origin = get_http_origin();
    if ($origin === 'https://yourfrontenddomain') {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourfrontenddomain");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        if ('OPTIONS' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
            status_header(200);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_filter('rest_authentication_errors', 'rest_filter_incoming_connections');
function rest_filter_incoming_connections($errors) {
    $request_server = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $origin = get_http_origin();
    if ($origin !== 'https://yourfrontenddomain') return new WP_Error('forbidden_access', $origin, array(
        'status' => 403
    ));
    return $errors;
}
```